# ASP.net MVC RC 2 - Won't Install... Because NGEN is having Catastrophic failures!

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I see that the new [ASP.NET MVC 1.0 Release Candidate 2](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=ee4b2e97-8a72-449a-82d2-2f720d421031&displaylang=en) is out.  [No posts](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/default.aspx) yet on Scott Gu's blog.  Any idea's if this has broken anything?  I'm currently using the beta version of the MVC with a couple of projects.  I am about to start a new one.

Does the RC 2 break anything when moving from the Beta version?

**[Update]** Not able to install RC2 "Setup Wizard Ended Permaturely" because of an error.
Here is [someone](http://tinyurl.com/badtw3) experiencing the same problem.  Any ideas?

**[Update]** Ok now I find that the dependancy on NGEN is the root of the failure.
NGEN is logging 'Catastrophic failure' and then shutting down.

Do I need to reinstall anything? the OS?

Comment: http://haacked.com/archive/2009/03/03/aspnetmvc-changes-for-rc2.aspx phil has posted. reading now

Answer (score 3):

I found **UPDATE** half an [answer](http://forums.asp.net/p/1380126/2916346.aspx).
The following services need to be running inorder for the installation to complete.

- .Net Optimization Service
- ASP.Net State Service

Just a pitty the optimization service isn't happy

Comment: ok next issue.  How do i get the Optimisation Service to start?
event log is logging critical failures for this service

Answer (score 1):

No breaking changes from RC1 to RC2 but I think there might have been a few going from BETA to RC1.

Scott Gu's usual epic blog post on ASP.NET RC1.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/01/27/asp-net-mvc-1-0-release-candidate-now-available.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this [hotfix](http://blogs.msdn.com/webdevtools/archive/2009/03/03/hotfix-available-for-asp-net-mvc-crashes-with-azure-power-commands-resharper.aspx). You can download it [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=16827&wa=wsignin1.0).

Phil Haack wrote about the problem here: http://haacked.com/archive/2009/03/06/hotfix-for-installing-aspnetmvc.aspx

It's likely that you're running into this issue too.